# MongoDB / Mongoose: MarkModified a nested object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Unfortunately I don't have a record I can test this on, but I can't find any information on this anywhere.

Say I have a document like this:

```
{
  email:  {
       type: 'Gmail',
       data: {//freeform data},
    }
}
```

I want to update `doc.email.data`. I need to use `markModified()` or else the data won't save correctly.

Do I mark modified like this?

```
doc.email.data = newData;
doc.markModified('email.data');
doc.save();
```

Or do I just do `markModified('email')` and Mongoose will work out the rest?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to provide the full path the modified object field, so it should be:

```
doc.markModified('email.data');
```

Comment: Thanks Johnny. Would doing `doc.markModified('email')` still cause the `data` property to be updated though? I assume it's just more expensive, which I don't want, but I'm trying to understand how this sort of thing works.

Comment: @Jascination I would expect that to also work, but it would update the whole `email` object instead of the just the `data` part that you need.

Comment: It's worth noting that calling `markModified` is not necessary when the nested object is a Mongoose subdocument, as it will have full change detection (except when using Dates and such).