# After editing doc using UI in MongoDB Atlas, issues with Mongoose .save() and .findOneAndUpdate()

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I'm new to programming and have a basic REST API using Express, Mongoose, and MongoDB (hosted on Atlas). I have a user schema and a blog schema as follows:

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: { type: String, minlength: 3, unique: true },
    passwordHash: String,
    name: String,
    blogs: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Blog'
    }]
})

const blogSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    author: String,
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    },
    url: String,
    likes: { type: Number, default: 0 }
})
```

Here is my code for the post request where I see the strange behaviour. It's a post request for 1) saving a new blog and then 2) updating the user doc to include that blog's id in an array in the user doc. I understand this might not be best practice from a db-perspective but let's just consider it as an experiment.

```
const blogsRouter = require('express').Router()
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const Blog = require('../models/blog')
const User = require('../models/user')

...

blogsRouter.post('/', async (request, response, next) => {
    try {
        if (request.body.title === undefined || request.body.url === undefined) {
            response.status(400).end()
        }

        const decodedToken = jwt.verify(request.token, process.env.SECRET)
        if (!request.token || !decodedToken.id) {
            return response.status(401).send({ error: 'Missing or invalid token' }) 
        }
        const user = await User.findById(decodedToken.id)

        const blog = new Blog({ 
            title: request.body.title,
            author: request.body.author,
            user: user,
            url: request.body.url,
            likes: request.body.likes
        })

        const savedBlog = await blog.save()
        if (savedBlog) {
            user.blogs = user.blogs.concat(savedBlog._id)
            // .markModified() as shown here doesn't seem to make a difference
            // user.markModified('blogs')
            await user.save()
            // Different behaviour if I use .findOneAndUpdate()
            // await User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: user.id }, { $set: user }, { new: true })
            response.status(201).json(savedBlog)
        } else {
            response.status(400).end()
        }

    } catch (exception) {
        next(exception)
    }

})
```

Everything was working fine until I noticed that if I open the MongoDB Atlas UI and manually edit any of the document properties for a user (using the pencil icon), I would no longer be able to .save() or .findOneAndUpdate() on that **one specific** user document.  Other user documents I can still save and edit. If I make a new user document it works as expected.

Specifically, the program doesn't throw an error but I get slightly different behaviour depending on whether I use .save() or .findOneAndUpdate(). For .save(), Postman waits indefinitely for a response — it seems to be stuck at the line `await user.save()`. For .findOneAndUpdate(), Postman receives the response but there is no update to the `blogs` property of the user doc.

Initially I thought the issue only occurred if I edited the `blogs` property. So I found suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35733647/mongoose-instance-save-not-working) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34780974/mongodb-mongoose-markmodified-a-nested-object) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47123599/mongoose-instance-save-not-working-when-embedded-array-object-changed). But it turns out that the problem can be recreated if I edit any property of the user.

I know I probably shouldn't be editing documents in the Atlas UI, but curious as to why this problem is occurring and whether there is anyway to fix it.

Comment: I guess you have a preSave hook for your user schema, please include it as well if possible.